# Webview not showing loaded content

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, webview, webkit

I'm trying to experiment with web view by using swift. I created a simple Xcode project, placed a web view within my application interface and connected it to my app delegate.swift with an outlet called "myview". By executing

self.myview.mainFrameURL = "http://www.google.com"

from within applicationDidFinishLaunching(), I would expect the Google's homePage to be loaded. However, this doesn't happen: the web view does not show anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

1) Add the NSAppTransportSecurity in your plist https://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/

2) check in your project settings that "Sandbox" is enabled and that internet connections are allowed

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call `loadRequest()` to make it load a page.

So basically:

```
[self.myWebView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
    [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.com"]]]
```

Comment: This is getting weird. After converting your example to Swift code, I get an error message saying that "WebView does not have any member named loadRequest()". According to the webView class reference, though, the method should exist. So, what's wrong?

Comment: What webview are you using? Is it the new `WKWebView` or the old `WebView` ?

Comment: It's called "WebKit Webview" and it is the only web-related view I can see in the object library.

Answer (score 0):

After digging into the console logs, I found the solution to my problem. I'm not sure if I can share it though, since I'm using a beta OS X version and this *restriction* could have been introduced to improve apps' security, even if from what I can see it can be disabled.

Comment: Now that OS X 10.11 is out, I can safely share the cause of the problem. It was AppTransportSecurity, a new technology introduced by Apple to restrict loading web content just from encripted sources. For a browser like application, though, the only ways to work properly is to completely disable it, which can be done by adding some keys in your info.plist file. See Apple's documentation for the implementation details :-)